# Raspberry Pi alternative with low power mode?

Tags: power-supply

The Pi has no low power mode. That's a shame.

Is there anything like the Pi that does have a low power mode?

Is SleepyPi or switching to ESP32/Arduino the only way?

Comment: Welcome -- but shopping recommendations are explicitly [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  You could try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the only way to do what?

Comment: The only way to get the Pi to sleep